# Can't get Web Socket to work on my no-ip domain name

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am trying to build an online chatting site with Web Socket. Whenever I changed the private IP address to my no-ip domain name, an error occurred. Why?

This works (Client JavaScript):

```
var wsUri = "ws://192.168.1.5:9000/chat/server.php";
```

This doesn't work (Client JavaScript):

```
var wsUri = "ws://moonvalley.no-ip.biz:9000/chat/server.php";
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that I need to perform port forwarding for my router too. I hope this will help others.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on how you fixed this? An example would be really helpful, I really stuck in this....

Comment: Basically you need to modify the settings of your router. To find out the router IP, note the default gateway as you type 'ipconfig' on Windows. Enter the IP on a browser address bar. Then navigate to Port Forwarding.

Comment: There are many YouTube tutorials on this, eg.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw